# Definable subsets of the order type $\mathbf\omega$, without use of paramaters.

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

Many will surely interpret this as a trivial question but I've found myself stuck on it for a while now.  The structures in question are linear orderings and the signature consists of only the symbol $<$, interpreted in the usual way.  The problem is to prove that all (non-parametrically) definable subsets of $\mathbf{\omega}$ are either finite or cofinite.  $\mathbf{\zeta}$ is defined to be the order type of the integers and the hint given is to look at $\mathbf{\omega}+\mathbf{\zeta}$ (as we know $\mathbf{\omega}\equiv\mathbf{\omega}+\mathbf{\zeta}\,$).

The closest I could get to finding an answer was in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378496/definable-with-parameters-example) as part of example 2 in the chosen solution - which I quote:

> It is easy to show that all definable subsets over the empty set are either finite or cofinite.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $\zeta $?

Comment: @Max $\mathbf{\zeta}$ is the order type of the integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: There is an automorphism of $\omega+\zeta$ that is the identity on $\omega$ and shifts each element of $\zeta$ forward by $1$.  What does this tell you about the definable subsets of $\omega+\zeta$?  Can you write a first-order property that all such subsets have, which when interpreted in $\omega$ means they are either finite or cofinite?